# Production function f(z1, z2, z3, z4) = min{α1z1, α2z2} + min {α3z3, α4z4}

Tags: microeconomics

Consider the following production function:
$$f(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = min\{α_1z_1, α_2z_2\} + min \{α_3z_3, α_4z4\}$$
The solution to the cost minimization problem requires $z1^* = z2^*$ and
$z3^* = z4^*$.

Is this statement true or false?

Comment: Hi! If you find this question too difficult to research and answer, you are not likely to have a good/useful time in the Economics course you are attending. If you have the option of dropping the course, I recommend doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: attached]
Sorry for not typing out, you can see my solution image: